# Issues with 'plus symbol' output in PSQL on update query

Tags: postgresql, update

Simple but frustrating issue... I'm trying to do an update command to correct a misspelling with this field:

```
grouper=> select * from master_list WHERE group ~ 'JustAdopted';
       group       | activity | usefulness 
-------------------+----------+------------
 JustAdoptedAdvice+|          |           
                   |          | 
(1 row)
```

But postgres won't give me a straight answer on the field name...

```
grouper=> UPDATE master_list SET group = 'JustAdoptingAdvice' WHERE group = 'JustAdoptedAdvice';
UPDATE 0

grouper=> UPDATE master_list SET group = 'JustAdoptingAdvice' WHERE group = 'JustAdoptedAdvice+';
UPDATE 0

grouper=> select * from master_list WHERE group ~ '+';
ERROR:  invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid
```

What is going on with that field? Why is that plus symbol there and what does it represent?

And how do I reference it to change it, if the field won't update with or without the symbol being there?

Comment: The operator `~` uses regular expressions to compare values. and `'+'` is an invalid regular expression (which is what the error message is telling you).

Comment: ok, so how do I update the field? And what does the plus mean exactly?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Remove the `+` sign? Details about regular expressions can be found here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP and here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: This is pretty clear in multiple places in the original post.  I'm trying to update the field, to correct a misspelling.

Comment: @some1 I think you need to study regular expressions though - if you want to say "ends with a plus" you don't write `~ '+'`, but `~ '\+$'`. In this case simpler to use an SQL `LIKE` pattern, e.g. `LIKE '%+'`. But actually the problem has nothing to do with ending with a plus, you're being thrown by how `psql` is displaying the value. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
UPDATE master_list
SET group = 'JustAdoptingAdvice' 
WHERE group = 'JustAdoptedAdvice+';
```

should work perfectly fine if the field was really `JustAdoptedAdvice+`, but I don't think it is. `psql` is showing that `+` to mean `continuation` ... I suspect there's actually a *newline* there.

```
UPDATE master_list
SET group = 'JustAdoptingAdvice' 
WHERE group = E'JustAdoptedAdvice\n';
```

There could be whitespace after the newline too, so maybe even:

```
UPDATE master_list
SET group = 'JustAdoptingAdvice' 
WHERE group ~ 'JustAdoptedAdvice[[:blank:]\n]+';
```

which says "JustAdoptedAdvice followed by one or more of tab/space/newline".

Demo showing it's likely to be a newline:

```
regress=> CREATE TABLE t4(x text);
CREATE TABLE
regress=> INSERT INTO t4(x) VALUES (E'JustAdoptedAdvice\n');
INSERT 0 1
regress=> SELECT * FROM t4;
         x         
-------------------
 JustAdoptedAdvice+

(1 row)
```

To be sure, look at the hex representation of the utf-8 encoding of the string:

```
regress=> SELECT encode( convert_to(x, 'utf-8'), 'hex') FROM t4;
                encode                
--------------------------------------
 4a75737441646f707465644164766963650a
(1 row)
```

You'll see that it ends with 0x0a, which is a newline.